# Objective-C symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception when overriding init on an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a subclass of NSMutableArray to create my own kind with a special object as the first one.

```
something = [[MyCustomMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in the implementation it crashes with __cxa_allocate_exception when adding the object:

```
#import "MyCustomMutableArray.h"

@implementation MyCustomMutableArray

-(instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]){

        [self addObject:@"The special"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you override all the methods that need to be overrided if you subclass `NSArray` (from which `NSMutableArray` inherits)? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray#overview

Comment: `NSArray` and friends are [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). Although subclassing is strongly discouraged, you can find information (and examples) on the linked page regarding subclassing.